# MemoryOutputStream is not a member of PxToolkit

Tags: c++, physx

I'm trying create a PhysX actor w/ a custom mesh., following the official doc:

```
static const PxVec3 convexVerts[] = {PxVec3(0,1,0),PxVec3(1,0,0),PxVec3(-1,0,0),PxVec3(0,0,1),PxVec3(0,0,-1)};


PxConvexMeshDesc convexDesc;
convexDesc.points.count     = 5;
convexDesc.points.stride    = sizeof(PxVec3);
convexDesc.points.data      = convexVerts;
convexDesc.flags            = PxConvexFlag::eCOMPUTE_CONVEX;
convexDesc.vertexLimit      = 256;

PxToolkit::MemoryOutputStream buf;
if(!cooking.cookConvexMesh(convexDesc, buf))
    return NULL;
PxToolkit::MemoryInputData input(buf.getData(), buf.getSize());
PxConvexMesh* convexMesh = thePhysics->createConvexMesh(input);
PxShape* aConvexShape = aConvexActor->createShape(PxConvexMeshGeometry(convexMesh), aMaterial);
```

Taken from [the official docs](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/physx/Docs/Shapes.html#convex-meshes).

But when I try to compile:

```
error C2039: 'MemoryOutputStream' is not a member of PxToolkit.
```

I've included the PxToolkit.lib file I manually built using VS 2013,as well as the headers. And indeed MOS is not in the PxTkStream.cpp.

Comment: Did you include the header that declares `PxToolkit::MemoryOutputStream`?

Comment: Well, there is no such header :( The PxTkStreams hdr/src is here https://gist.github.com/vinz243/294308f6e891118f06bb

Comment: If no header declares that type, and you don't declare it, how do you expect the compiler to know what it is?

Comment: Well, that's the weird problem. Is the tutorial out of date? What should I do?

Comment: Search for `MemoryOutputStream` in all the headers provided by the library.

Comment: Searched with sublime text, nothing seemed to match. Here are the result if you wanna take a look https://gist.github.com/vinz243/7a7eab187ea7596218a3

Answer (score 0):

a bit late but you should just use `PxDefaultMemoryInputData` and `PxDefaultMemoryOutputStream` according to the docs